# How to repeat a for loop iteration c#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, iteration, repeat

Let's assume the following example:

```
int Lenght = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < Length; i ++)
{
    if(i == 5)
    {

    }
}
```

Let's say at i = 5, I want the loop to repeat until the condition (x) is met, before continuing to other iterations. How do I keep the if statement running until the condition (x) is available?

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to do. If I understand you correctly and you want to keep doing the same top-level loop until some condition is met, I would just reset the counter. e.g. `if (i == 5 && !condition) { i = 4;}`. The loop counter will then increment that to 5 again.

Comment: so you mean I can set the counter to i = 4. OK, I will give that a try.

Comment: What you are doing is a blocking operation, which means that instead if changing the loop counter, you can sit in an internal while loop until conditions are met.

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following, although it's not really a good idea. What are you trying to do?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (i == 5)
    {
        while (!condition(x)) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @InBetween,  but I was wondering , is it possible to set the counter to i = 5 , and keep it at that point untill I finish doing other stuff, and then let i increment as normal ?

Answer (score 1):

> lets say at i = 5, I want the loop to repeat until condition (x) is met

To me, this sounds like you want the loop to perform the same logic until `x` is met.  For example, if you were printing the value of `i` in each iteration of the loop, you'd want to continue printing `5` until `x` is met.

Therefore, instead of using a `for` loop, I'd suggest using a `while` loop instead:

```
int length = 20;
int i = 0;
while (i < length)
{
    Print(i); // This is just an example.

    if (i == 5 && !condition(x))
    {
        x++; // Do something with x.  Again, an example.
        continue;
    }

    i++;
}
```

The `continue` statement moves the loop to its next iteration, which means the `i++` statement won't be executed until the condition with `x` is met.

Going with my example about printing the value of `i`, let's say you wanted to print the numbers `1` to `10`, but you wanted to print the `5` 3 times. You could do that like this:

```
int length = 10;
int i = 1;
int x = 1;
while (i <= length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    if (i == 5 && x < 3)
    {
        x++;
        continue;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Lenght = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < Length; i ++)
{
    // this loop iterate through all values
    // lets say at i = 5, I want the loop to repeat until conition (x) is met 
    // before continuing to other iterations
    if(i == 5)
    {   // For example sake assuming x is an int and 10 is your exit val
        // Post more code for a better answer
        while (x != 10)
        {
            x++;
        }
}
```

}